# Aside from the Arizal has anybody else been able to identify an unknown grave through supernatural means?

Tags: arizal, ruach-hakodesh

It’s said that many of the Kevarim in Tzfas were unknown until the Ari used Ruach Hakodesh to identify them. Has anybody else before or since been able to do this or was he the first & only?

Comment: Consider the Convoy of the 35

Comment: I have heard of this before, but I don’t know if was the Arizal who actually found the burial site of Yoshki. Looking for the source at the moment.

Comment: This is the information that I found in Sefer called Kabbalah a Targum / Feldheim. I have attached picture instead of writing it out. ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp92w.jpg)

Comment: Isn’t there such a story with R’ Shimon bar Yochai?

Comment: @DonielF Do you mean [this](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.34a.2)? (It's easy to remember the citation because it starts on ל"ג and extends into the beginning of ל"ד.)

Comment: @WAF Yes, that’s it. I’m not sure if the OP would count it, though; is he talking about this kind of story, or is he talking about a case where we have the grave and don’t know who’s buried there?

Comment: @DonielF Hard to say because I do not know the Ariza"l story to which we are comparing. Lages, perhaps linking or summarizing the story would help, in addition to specifying what type of grave identification you are looking for.

Comment: A remote cousin helped in a cemetery, where all the tombs had been stolen. Since he only had a [special device](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground-penetrating_radar) instead of _ruach hakodesh,_ he could only show the locations of the graves without the names, but it was still quite a big thing.

Comment: The prominent kabbalists, R. Yosef Dayan (A.K.A. The Tailor) and R. Yosef Waltuch (A.K.A. The Holy Broom-sweeper [of Jerusalem]) were known to identify unknown graves. Unfortunately, I don’t recall specific graves offhand.

Answer (score 2):

Hat-tip to @DoubleAA. There are two sources for this answer.

1] [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convoy_of_35) (W)

2] [“A Tzaddik in our time”](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tzaddik-Our-Time-Rabbi-Aryeh/dp/1598262491)  pp 162, 3. (T)

W describes the story of the Convoy of 35, of which

> only 23 of the 35 bodies could be identified.

T writes pp 162, 3

> the young martyrs were reburied in in Jerusalem's military cemetery on
>   Mount Herzl. On 23, markers were placed (and later, tombstones). Each
>   grave had its name. Yet twelve remained unmarked.

W:

> To solve the problem, (*i.e to identify the bodies*) Rabbi Aryeh Levin
>   performed the rare goral ha-gra (ha-gra = Vilna Gaon) ceremony, a
>   process in which the reader of the Torah is led to certain verses which
>   give hints as to the subjects in question.

The end of the story T:

> And no one had the slightest doubt that the determination was accurate
>   – that every one of the 12 out of the 35 had been rightly identified.